# No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode9

I am trying to upload an app in App store. But every time when I try it gets failed. it gives me following error

[image]

But I have double check it,the Id is same.

**What I Have done After getting that error multiple times**

- I deleted my certificates and app ID and provision profiles
- I created all other again. (Certificates, app Id and profiles)
- I registered that app on newly created Bundle Identifier

**but still I am getting this error. Have a look at Bundle Id that I am using. I am not printing it fully though**

"MyAppName as Prefix - com.ma........"

there is a prefix and then the Bundle Id is same. So I think prefix is creating problem to bring that  error.

I have really no Idea why this error is keep on showing whereas everything is setup as expected. Any Help ???